# No setter method for assignment to property swift 3 with objective-c

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am using below code in one of my swift classes:

```
    import UIKit

public class BRUFIMobile: NSObject {

    public var mobileNumber : NSString?
    public var provider : NSString?
    public var aliasName: NSString?
    public var aliasName_en : NSString?
    @objc public var isDefault: Bool

    public override init() {
        self.isDefault = false
        super.init()
    }

}
```

My project contains both objective-c and swift codes. The code works fine on xCode 7 but now by updating to xCode 8 I get below error:

```
No setter method 'setIsDefault:' for assignment to property
```

I use the attribute in my objective-c code like below:

```
   + (BRUFIMobile *) convertUFIMobileToBRUFIMobile:(UFIMobile *) ufimobile
{
    BRUFIMobile *brUFIMobile = [[BRUFIMobile alloc] init];
    brUFIMobile.mobileNumber = ufimobile.number;
    brUFIMobile.provider = ufimobile.provider;
    brUFIMobile.aliasName = ufimobile.aliasName;
    brUFIMobile.aliasName_en = ufimobile.aliasName_en;
    brUFIMobile.isDefault = [ufimobile.isDefault boolValue];

    return brUFIMobile;
}
```

is it now neccessary to define seetters manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift 3 beta makes special treatment for properties with leading `is`.
For the property `isDefault`, Swift generates `isDefault` as getter and `setDefault:` as setter (not `setIsDefault:`).

Use `setDefault:` in your Objective-C code, or make it a computed property and give `@objc` names manually.

---

(Addition)
"make it a computed property" means something like this:

```
private var _default: Bool = false
public var isDefault: Bool {
    @objc(isDefault) get {
        return _default
    }
    @objc(setIsDefault:) set {
        self._default = newValue
    }
}
```

---

(Update)
As far as I tested, this seems to work:

```
@objc(isDefault) public var isDefault: Bool
```

A little bit simpler than "making it a computed property". Please try.

---

(Update2)

Apple Staff has confirmed that "This is a known issue that will be fixed in a future beta:"
https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/3254

This is not a Core Data case. But the fix will work for this issue as well.
(It's a pity, as for now, Xcode 8 beta 2 does not include this fix.)

---

(Update3)
It is said in Xcode 8 beta 3 Release Notes that this feature is removed and I have confirmed that, with no `@objc` attribute, Objective-C setter `setIsDefault:` is available for `Bool` property `isDefault`.

Comment: I do not understand this part: "make it a computed property and give @objc names manually." may you please specify it more?

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad , Added an example in my answer.