# Xcode 8 and Swift 3 Crashes with -[Project.Video setMine:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, swift3

When I try to access the boolean attribute of core data entity(`Video`), App is getting crashed at `-[Project.Video setMine:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

1. In my `Video+CoreDataProperties.Swift` file I have included the property as `@NSManaged var isMine: NSNumber!`
2. Also I have the same property named `isMine` in my `Video` Entity on `xcdatamodeld`.
3. I'm trying to set the bool value at `video?.isMine = NSNumber(value: false)`, but app crashes with below exception.

`-[Project.Video setMine:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Did `Swift 3` has changed the boolean property to remove 'is' prefix? if So, Do we need to change the attribute name to 'mine' instead of 'isMine' as well as in Core data `xcdatamodeld` file?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be the same issue with this. [No setter method for assignment to property swift 3 with objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161580/no-setter-method-for-assignment-to-property-swift-3-with-objective-c). Try this: `@NSManaged @objc(isMine) var isMine: NSNumber!`.

Comment: @OOPer, Your work around is seems to be working fine. Thanks!